# Need JavaScript Geolocation and General JavaScript Assistance

Tags: javascript, function, geolocation

I am "attempting" to use JavaScript's geolocation functions, but I am having issues with, I assume, the way JavaScript works. I have found many examples on how to use the geolocation functions and they all, basically, look like this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){alert("Your Coordinates:\nLatitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "\nLongitude: " + position.coords.longitude);});
```

The above code works, but I am trying to do is something like this:

```
function geoMe(){
    var position = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
    var geoLocationDiv = document.getElementById('geoLocationDiv');
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    geoLocationDiv.innerHTML = latitude + "," + longitude;
}
```

As you can probably guess, it isn't working. I have never been good at interpreting code that is all "jammed" together like the example, so I am VERY confused.

In looking at the example code, it looks like there is a function called "getCurrentPosition". Now, here is where I get lost. It looks like there is a function being passed in as a parameter to getCurrentPosition that has [as a parameter] a parameter called "position". Where did the "position" parameter come from??? I have seen where a function (without an actual function name) is used as a parameter, but it is REALLY confusing to me. Typically, I do something like:

```
function functionName(parameter1, parameter2, parameterN){
    function body
}
```

I know it is supposed to be advanced to do stuff like this, but I am a simple man, and I like my code simple, and I like my functions to have names.

So, can anybody out there help me with getting this GeoLocation stuff to work the way I want it to work? And, maybe along the way, explain this bizarre method of JavaScript functions?

Thank you, and have a great day.    :-)

Comment: You seem to not be a JavaScript programmer. The `getCurrentPosition` method expects a callback function as its first argument. That callback function then receives the `position` object as *its* first argument.

Comment: No, I am not an everyday JavaScript programmer. I know the basics, and that's it.

Comment: Well, client-side (browser) JavaScript is all about callback functions, I can tell you that `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
function geoMe () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function ( pos ) {
        document.getElementById('geoLocationDiv').innerHTML =
                pos.coords.latitude + "," + pos.coords.longitude;
    });
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/K6sKe/1/

You have to pass a function object to the `getCurrentPosition` method. That function acts as the callback function, and is invoked when the user gives permission to access its location. In our case, our callback function is a anonymous function expression. The `getCurrentPosition` method is designed to call the callback passing the Position object to it. So, our function expression defines one formal argument (`pos`) which represents the Position object. Within the callback, we can access that Position object.

Comment: (1) you HAVE to pass a function object as a parameter to the getCurrentPosition method? There is no way to do it another way, more straight forward? (2) You have to use an anonymous function?

Comment: @Brian (1) Afaik. You can read the specification of that method [in the Geolocation API standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#get-current-position). Also, MDN has a [page on how to use geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_geolocation). (2) Any function object.

Comment: I'll check out the links, thanks. It looks like I'll need to study up on "anonymous function" and "callback function".

Answer (score 1):

It's not that bizarre if you simply look at getCurrentPosition as just another function that takes in one parameter. However, that parameter happens to be an anonymous function. Here's a very simple example to illustrate the idea of a callback function.

```
function sayHi(myFunction) {
    alert(myFunction());
}

sayHi(function() {return 'Hello World'});
```

In the above, sayHi is a function that takes in a parameter called myFunction, and myFunction is just a function that returns the string 'Hello World'. This is obviously a overly simplified example which you can easily achieve by passing a string. But using this approach gives you more flexibility and cleaner code when functions get more complex.

Comment: Hmmm ... looks like I'll be Googling "anonymous functions" and "callback functions". Thank you.